# How can I stream video from UDP source and display on Android/iOS device with C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, video-streaming, libvlcsharp

I need to stream video coming from my drone through UDP port and use some kind of video player to display on my Android/IOS device.

I've already tried to use LIBVLC player to do it but got some issues.

The problem with the LibVLC is that the receiving packet size is 1416 but LibVLC need to receive 1316

```
string UDP_VIDEO_URL = "udp://@:11111";
LibVLC _libvlc = new LibVLC();
VideoView0.MediaPlayer.Play(new Media(_libvlc, UDP_VIDEO_URL, FromType.FromLocation));
```

Comment: Have you checked if the drone manufacture has public SDKs and specifications of their streaming data? Without that, it would be a wild guess to what needs to be done....

Comment: It's working with the apk "VLC player for android". But not sure with libvlc. Is is working?

Comment: Share your full code so we can repro. If it works with vlc-android, it can work with libvlcsharp